# SAT Correct this faulty usage of "when"

Tags: grammar

Sentence that needs correction : "A dilemma is ***when*** a person is faced with two or more choices, each of which leads to undesirable consequences.

Why is the use of when wrong? Why should when be ommitted?

Comment: A dilemma is not an event, so how can when be used?

Comment: You are right, I would accept this usage in casual speech, but it is obvious that this question comes from SAT practice.

Comment: @Phil yes it's from sat. but a dilemma isn't a person either so I don't think the sentence itself makes sense. what's a better way to write the sentence?

Comment: This use of *when* is perfectly acceptable in most circumstances. It's (arguably) not correct in formal grammar, but omitting it would be even worse: * "A dilemma is a person is faced..."

Comment: "A dilemma is a situation in which ..."

Comment: Sometimes situations or events are used as examples of what a word means, as in the case of "dilemma" here. In that usage, it is ok to use "when" for explanatory purposes when describing the circumstances.

Comment: *"I've always said [that power is **when** people think you have power]"* -- Tip O'Neill with William Novak, *Man of the House*, 1987 (from *MWCDEU* page 777)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but when you take tests you're required to do some mind reading: can you guess what the test writer thinks is wrong?  Unfortunately, this is a useful skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this sentence is perfectly fine in casual speech it is not quite as correct as possible. "When" specifies a point in time, while a dilemma refers to a situation.

> A situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or
>   more alternatives, especially equally undesirable ones
>   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dilemma

The correct answer would be: "A dilemma is **a situation in which** a person is faced with two or more choices [...]"

The question obviously was produced from this definition.

Answer (score 1):

As some comments have said, that sentence is fine in casual speech.

In formal speech, the problem is with "is when" not just "when." The word "is" expects to be followed by a noun or an adjective, like "A dilemma is a kind of problem." On the other hand, "when," expects to say when something happens, like "The ground is wet when it is raining."

Replacing "is" with "occurs" would be fine: "A dilemma occurs when a person is faced..."

You should  **not**  simply omit "when" in this case, because "a dilemma is a person..." immediately causes a problem: A dilemma is not a kind of person.